# Getting error while doing api call and android app is crash

Tags: android

i am new to android, i m trying to api call with php , i have done one example for it, that work on another computer fine but same app package gives error in eclipse on my laptop.

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
} `
```

hear is my error log, i got this much of errors.

Comment: Post your logcat output. Without it, it is hard to tell where did actual problem occured.

Comment: i added logcat output

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try following way    
//List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs 
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost hp = new HttpPost(url);
UrlEncodedFormEntity obj=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
obj.setChunked(true);
hp.setEntity(obj);
HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hp);   
HttpEntity he = hr.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Logcat is clear: `Could not find a method postData(View) in the activity class`. I guess you've used xml layout for setting button action.

In this case, just change your

```
public void postData() {
}
```

to

```
public void postData(View view) {
}
```

Note: setting button listeners this way isn't efficient.

Also, you should perform network operations on another thread - using network on main thread will raise [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) on Android 3.0+

Comment: Very first time it works fine.. but after 2-3 time i running it, without no change is crash app.

Comment: @krunal please check your stack trace - the crash is probably irrelevant to your original problem

Comment: pls , reframe your answer.. i cant understand.

Comment: @krunal does Logcat still shows `E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-25 18:12:19.722: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method postData(View) in the activity class com.example.apipostdata.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'sendbtn' ` error?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)

Comment: @krunal could you please post the complete stack trace (logcat output)?

Comment: hello,  Vladimir , you find logcat output at top of this post, just copy it and past to Ms Word..

Comment: @krunal your new error is not related to the original one. In your logcat: `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.gtc.projects.stepinsolutions.in 04-30 12:55:29.372:` check that you have correct url passed to constructor of `HttpPost` and that it is actually accessible from your machine

Comment: @krunal exception is `UnknownHostException`, which means that host name can't be resolved to ip-address. if it works fine on another machine, perhaps you have a dns problem.